# PHP session is not read in css file

Tags: php, css, session

I have two files, one is a php file where a session is set, the source is included below.
An .htaccess file is in place to make sure css will be parsed like a php file,
I have verified that this works, but no session data can be read from style2.css

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['bgimg'] = 'picture.jpg';
?>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>
....
```

the other is style2.css:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");



print_r($_SESSION);

?>

body {
    background: #fff;
    background-image: url("<?php echo $_SESSION['bgimg']; ?>");
}
....
```

Comment: How are you determining that "no session data can be read from style2.css"?

Comment: are you really mixing PHP and css

Comment: I think you are better off just modifying the body tag with a style attribute.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to read session in you stylesheets.

Comment: I will use a <style> tag in de header then, but thought it would work because some website use .php in their .html documents in the same way as this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your session cookie might not be sent along with .css requests, so the session cannot be fetched.

Comment: You can also just link to main.css.php or something.

Answer (score 0):

> css will be parsed like a php file,

This is a terrible idea!

Instead use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite `style2.css` to a PHP script

```
RewriteRule ^style2\.css$ generate_style.php
```

---

Other than that your session code looks fine, maybe PHP is just confused about the `.css` file.

Comment: sadly my hoster does not allow mod_rewrite, otherwise this also would have been my first choice.

Comment: That is .. very strange. I don't think I've ever seen that before. Not allowing RewriteRule but allowing AddType? That's crazy.

Answer (score 0):

In general, passing css files though the php interpreter is not the best idea.
Css is meant to be static, cached data with styling information.

As it seems that you want to dynamically set a background image of one specific element, I suggest using the `style` attribute in html like so:

```
<body style="background-image:url(<?= /* php code here */ ?>);"></body>
```

If, on the other hand, you want to change styling based for example on your login status, I suggest using html `class` attributes as flags and using the class selector in css:

Example CSS:

```css
p {
    /* formatting without login */
}
.login p {
    /* formatting with login */
}
```

Example php

```
<!-- snip -->
<body <? if(/* check login here */) { echo 'class="login"'}?> >
<!-- snip -->
```